# Can I apply for a Gold Seal any time, or only when I renew my CFI certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, cfi

Basically my CFI certificate expires almost a year from now, but I have met the requirements for Gold Seal. Can I obtain my Gold Seal now, or do I have to wait until its time to renew my CFI?

Comment: I think you can apply at any time, you will be issued a new certificate with the gold seal upon demonstrating your accomplishment to an examiner.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply now. It will be reissued every time you renew your certificate.

http://www.pilotratings.com/goldseal.html